# How to get id from seo friendly url using php?

Tags: php, function, url, seo

How do i get the id of the user from seo friendly url?

Here's the url (1 is the id)

http://www.website.com/users/edit/1

And, if the url is http://www.website.com/users/edit/1/stack-overflow/ in this case how do i find the id?

I am trying to get it as `<?php user = User::find($_GET['id']); ?>` but id doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$url = explode("/",($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])); 
print_r($url); 
?>
```

In your case $url[2] should have the ID that you are after...

Comment: Who ever marked this down as a -1, it would be great if they can explain why, because this will do exactly as he has asked for...

Comment: Wasn't me who voted you down, but voted back up because you are quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is using `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` to assign the `$_GET` variables:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users/edit/(.*)/(.*)$ users/edit/?user_id=$1&somethingelse=$2 [L,NC]
```

Then in your php script:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$somethingelse = $_GET['somethingelse'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... I think you should tell us more about the class or framework you are using... But whatever you are doing can't work at all. Because $_GET would only contain something if you would actually pass parameters in the ?id=123 way in the url... So this find will search for nothing because $_GET is empty.

Comment: Yup, i know that. I guess i will use variable instead of $_GET

Answer (score 0):

Parse the super global `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which will contain something like `users/edit/1/stack-overflow/`, with regex or `substr` and `strpos`